# How can I dynamically create Triggers in Spring Boot using Quartz?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a code like this:

```
@Component
public class SampleJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private SampleTask sampleTask;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        sampleTask.imprimir();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetail jobDetail(){
        return JobBuilder.newJob().ofType(SampleJob.class)
                .storeDurably()
                .withIdentity("Quartz_Job_Detail")
                .withDescription("Estoy invocando el job de ejempo")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public  Trigger trigger(JobDetail jobDetail){
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity("Quartz_Trigger")
                .withDescription("Trigger de ejemplo")
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().repeatForever().withIntervalInMilliseconds(5000))
                .build();
    }

}
```

In this case imprimir() is a function that only prints a text to know that quartz is working. The above code creates a trigger that run every 5 seconds. Now, what I want to do is to create multiple triggers based in the elements of a list taken from a database. Each Triggers has to have different Scheduled time. How can I create multiple triggers with different trigger times using a loop or something?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a durable job once and then create all triggers for that job.

```
@Service
class QuartzService {

   @Autowired
   private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

   void init(List<MyTrigger> triggers) {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
        scheduler.addJob(job(), true);

        for (MyTrigger myTrigger: triggers) {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger(myTrigger));
        } 
    }

    private JobDetail job() {
        return JobBuilder.newJob(SampleJob.class)
            .withIdentity("QuartzJob", "QuartzJob")
            .storeDurably()
            .build();
    }

    private Trigger trigger(MyTrigger trigger) {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(trigger.name)
            .withSchedule( 
                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(trigger.schedule))
            .forJob("QuartzJob", "QuartzJob")
            .build();
    }
}

class MyTrigger {
    String name;
    String schedule;
}
```

So, here you only need to pass a List of MyTrigger to QuartsService.init() method and it will create dynamically the triggers with its own schedule.